# Scala regex for hashtags

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm new guy in IT, and most of the things I manage to solve using google search, but I couldn't do it successfully this time so I decided to ask for some help, hehe.

I'm writing code in scala which is using twitter to pick popular hashtags.
I have managed to solve problem spliting every word separately, and then picking only those which start with #.

```
val tweetwords = statuses.flatMap(tweetText => tweetText.split(" "))

val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))
```

Because there is alot of hashtags on twitter using asian letters,and I only wanted to pick those using like english alphabet and numbers. I have tried to add some expression variations like:

```
val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => word.startsWith("#[^A-Za-z0-9]+"))
```

But when I am trying to print them after, they are not displayed. Same expression on regex testing websites is working perfectly fine.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2):

`startsWith` does not take a regex unfortunately, so that filter is looking explicitly for that regex string. You would need to construct a regex object like this:

```scala
val hashtagFilter = "^#[A-Za-z0-9]+$".r
```

You can then use this to filter tweet words:

```scala
val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => hashtagFilter.findFirstIn(word).isDefined)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will definitely remember this from now on how to work with regex!